# Draggable Panels stuck with CSS-Settings

Tags: html, css, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am playing around in my first ASP.net/HTML/CSS Application.

I need draggable panels and used Ajax-Control-Toolkit, it works good and I am only using one panel so far!

It looks like this:[image]

Now I want to fit the panels into its parent-containers "div"-containers, you can see them in the background, with borders (LEFT,TOP,BOTTOM).I have used those CSS-Settings for the children-panels:

```
.dragpanel-left {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;

    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

The problem is, when I use it like this, it gets overwritten by element.style{},
I tried to use `!important` but the panel can't be resized nor moved then.

Any idea how to solve this problem? Is there a "use !important once" tag or something so when the site is built, the panel is placed into its parent and after that can be freely moved?

Answer (score 0):

element style is higher in the [css hierarchy](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/css-specificity-hierarchy-what-you-need-to-know/), means that you have to replace it at runtime (or not set it at all to let css being mean).

think about using `js` and events like `dragstart`, `dragend` and so on to manipulat the element style

Comment: Where can I find element.style then? It isn't in my css-sheet.

Comment: if you never used `javascript` or `javascript events` take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp and then to integrate it in a asp page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx, btw you need a little bit of study :)

Comment: Yeah.. Well, I know Java pretty well and would've used Vaadin-Framework but I am kinda forced to use ASP.net and I have no experience in building websites like this, using HTML and JS. :p